# What is the difference among the three terms "research study", "research" and "study"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, difference

What is the difference among the three terms "research study", "research" and "study"?, please help me!, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked up _research_ and _study_ in the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say sometimes they're interchangeable, depending on the context. Below is the common definition of each term:

*Study* refers to a single paper or project, for example: **This study showed that massage was effective in reducing stress.** ← this paper states that massage was effective in reducing stress

*Research* includes a whole process of performing research: you look deeper into a topic by investigating the topic with different methods, including collecting data, performing trial(s)/experiment(s), and/or reading studies conducted by others... etc. in order to establish facts and reach new conclusions. For example: **Avoiding bias is important when conducting research.**

*Research study* is a scientific study on a particular topic which includes the process of research and new research results. A study purely based on existing materials without presenting new conclusions will not be called a research study (for example: literature reviews).